# Read user input and update a file using that input using bash

Tags: bash, shell, file-handling

I have a need to write a bash script which takes username and password from command line and then encrypts the password and update a file with the username and encrypted password.Say there is existing file admin.conf and it has fields like:
'''
A = 123
B = 456
C = 789
username = abc
pass = def
D = 000
'''

Then what the user entered as input in username and pass when we ran the bash script that input should get stored here in username and pass fields in the file (password being stored in encrypted form).

Since I am very new to bash scripting any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Reading something _from the command line_, encrypting a string, or changing the configuration file?

Comment: I was getting stuck in encrypting and changing the config file, thanks community for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Enter username: " USERNAME
read -rp "Enter password: " -s PASSWORD
ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD=$(openssl passwd -1 -stdin <<<"${PASSWORD}")

echo -e "\n"
awk -F= \
    -v OFS="= " \
    -i inplace \
    -v user="${USERNAME}" \
    -v pw="${ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD}" '
    /^username *=/{$2 = user}
    /^pass *=/{$2 = pw}
1' admin.conf
```

---

```
$ ./tst.sh
Enter username: John Doe
Enter password: 

$ cat admin.conf 
A = 123 
B = 456
C = 789
username = John Doe
pass = $1$5DzfvGYI$3GXWG9klLqq0dvgA3Panq.
D = 000
```